# PHP: How to use variable as closure type for Dependency Injection

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to handle a lot of errors, likes below:

```
App::error(function(App\Exceptions\RuntimeException $exception, $code) use ($someOther) { ... }
```

Any usage can I use variable as a type(for denpendency injection)?

```
$errorTypes = [ ... ];

foreach ($errorTypes as $errType) {

    App::error(function($errType $exception, $code) use ($someOther) {
```

Comment: You may hint `callable` meta-type. Also, pass a declared closure object there would be possible.

Comment: type will be used for dependency injection, so I can't use `callable` for that.